# Python interpreter in VScode issue

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image]

My vscode is showing select interpreter for python on clicking it says python not installed when python 3.11 is installd on my mac
tried creating virtual environment and downloading interpreter nothing possible

Comment: then choose the option **Enter Interpreter Path** and browse to the location of your `python` executable, in the virt env or the python 3.11 install, you have installed python or the virt env in a location VSC does not look for interpreters

Answer (score 1):

1. First check that you have installed and set the system environment variables correctly for Python.
2. If setting the environment variable still does not automatically find the Python interpreter, select the first option **Enter interpreter path** to choose python interpreter.
3. Another way is to add `"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "Path\\to\\your\\interpreter",` to your user `settings.json` (shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P** and search for **Preferences: Open User Settings**)

You can read [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter) for more details.